# DTO Between two Classes

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

So this got asked here a thousand times but nothing helped me so far.

Problem:

I have a class that receives data from my Controller, transferring this data to an API and get a Result.
So far it worked.

but now I am stuck because I have to do something like this

Controller --> ARequestClass --> BRequestClass-->CientClass recive  data --> ClientClass response data -->BResultClass-->AResultClass-->Controller

The Connection between the Controller and ARequestClass works.
The Connection between BRequestClass and the ClienClasst works

but how can I say witch Property from ArequestClass belongs to BRequestClass

I tried AutoMapper and watched and read tones of DTO stuff but all of them couldn't help me :|

it looks like this

```
public class ARequest
{
    public string AText { get; set; }
    public string AProductKey { get; set; }
    public string ASettings { get; set; }
}
public class BRequest
{
    public string BText { get; set; }
    public string BProductKey { get; set; }
    public string BSettings { get; set; }
}
public class ClientClass
{
    public BResult DoSomething(BRequest request)
    {
        client.something = $"www.anRandomApi.com/{request.BText}{request.BProductKey}{request.BSettings};
        return client;
    }
}
```

I know its an easy problem and the solution should be very easy but I'm having a brain fart and need  some help

Comment: Are you saying that you need to transform ARequest into BRequest?

Comment: They differ only in the names of the properties?

Comment: In automapping libraries you can usually add a specific configuration for specific types and explicitly choose which property gets mapped to which.

Comment: Kinda 
My instructor just told me to do that and today he has a day off.
He said it's for Modularity so we can reuse ARequestClass and change BRequestClass without making big changes to ARequestClass

Comment: BTW a need to map one request/dto to another looks like a code/design smell and might suggest that there is some deeper problem in your project

Comment: @BartoszKP ok let me phrase it like this.... I couldn't find a good tutorial that did it for me...
The Project is fine...according to my instructor 
He just let me sit on charcoal for a week and then helps me.

And I have just 2 Weeks of experience with C# and VS  2017 in generall.

I managed to get an API working.
Getting the Correct results and everything.
It bugs me that I'm Stuck to this "easy" Problem.
BrainFart ^10

Comment: How did you configure automapper? The Docs are here : http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whenever possible it's better to avoid having to manually specify mappings between properties. I'm not sure if there's a good reason in your case why it's `AProductKey` and `BProductKey` and not simply `ProductKey` in both (which AutoMapper would handle for you automatically). *If* the issue relates to serialization, a better approach in your classes might be to use the `JsonProperty` attribute to map from a JSON object into a more maintainable property in C#.

Anyway, you can specify the mapping for specific properties using AutoMapper (recommended way):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ARequest, BRequest>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.BText, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.AText))
        .ForMember(d => d.BProductKey, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AProductKey))
        .ForMember(d => d.BSettings, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ASettings));
});
```

Or, if you want the more dangerous option that saves you mapping each property individually (I would avoid this in production code):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ARequest, BRequest>()
        .ForAllMembers(mo =>
        {
            var convertedName = mo.DestinationMember.Name;
            if (convertedName.StartsWith("B"))
            {
                convertedName = "A" + convertedName.Substring(1);
            }
            mo.MapFrom(convertedName);
        });
});
```

Alternatively, you could do this without AutoMapper by adding a constructor to BRequest that takes an ARequest:

```
public class BRequest
{
    public BRequest() { }

    public BRequest(ARequest source)
    {
        this.BText = source.AText;
        this.BProductKey = source.AProductKey;
        this.BSettings = source.ASettings;
    }

    public string BText { get; set; }
    public string BProductKey { get; set; }
    public string BSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The alternative way without automapper did it for me.
Thank You.